# error yii2 upload Call to a member function saveAs() on null

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am new programmer world and ask for your help guys,
I have error "Call to a member function saveAs() on null"

This code in models

```
[['file'],'file'],
```

- this code in controllers

  ```
              $docfileload = $model->docname;
          $model->file = UploadedFile::getinstance($model,'file');
          $model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$docfileload.'.'.$model->file->extension);
          $model->save();

          //save path in db
          $model->docfile = 'uploads/'.$docfileload.'.'.$model->file->extension;
  ```

this code in _form

```
    <?= $form->field($model,'file')->fileinput(); ?>
```

after I used getInstanceByName like @bluehipy told me I have a new issue look to the pic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0aVC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
    $model->file=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');  
    $model->pic=$model->file->extension; // pic is a field in database varchar(20)  
    $model->save(false) ;

    $ImageName=$model->id;
    if (!file_exists('uploads/'.$ImageName)) {
    mkdir('uploads/'.$ImageName, 0777, true);
        }   
    $model->file->saveAs( 'uploads/'.$ImageName.'/'.$ImageName.'.'.$model-
    >file->extension );
```

`

Answer (score 0):

`UploadedFile::getinstance` returns an `array` of files. Use `getInstanceByName` or `UploadedFile::getinstance($model, 'file')[0]`.

Comment: I try getInstanceByName but I have new message error 'Illegal offset type in isset or empty'

Comment: @Abdul-FattahEl-Hamali where? What line?

Comment: public static function getInstanceByName($name)
    {
        $files = self::loadFiles();
        return isset($files[$name]) ? new static($files[$name]) : null;    //stop in this line
    }

Comment: return isset($files[$name]) ? new static($files[$name]) : null;

Comment: @Abdul-FattahEl-Hamali update your current code so I can see exactly your context.