# Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Current PHP version: 7.1.7

please help me I have this problem

> Illegal offset type in isset or empty at line 113

I have this problem after I decided to upload files to my website

in C:\xampp\htdocs\archive\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\UploadedFile.php
line 113:

```
 public static function getInstanceByName($name)
{
    $files = self::loadFiles();
    return isset($files[$name]) ? new static($files[$name]) : null;
}
```

and guys if this not clear ask me for more explication and thanks

This code in models

```
[['file'],'file'],
```

- this code in controllers

  ```
              $docfileload = $model->docname;
          $model->file = UploadedFile::getinstancebyname($model,'file');
          $model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$docfileload.'.'.$model->file->extension);
          $model->save();

          //save path in db
          $model->docfile = 'uploads/'.$docfileload.'.'.$model->file->extension;
  ```

this code in _form

```
    <?= $form->field($model,'file')->fileinput(); ?>
```

in first I used getInstance() but replecd getInstanceByName() because had porblem here

[error yii2 upload Call to a member function saveAs() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45902581/error-yii2-upload-call-to-a-member-function-saveas-on-null)

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Which PHP version you are using?

Comment: Current PHP version: 7.1.7

Comment: Where you are using getInstanceByName method? whats the need of it?

Comment: @KamranKhatti Method `getInstance()` is using `getInstanceByName()`.

Comment: in first I used getInstance() but replecd getInstanceByName()

Comment: After replacing issue resolved?

Comment: yes after replacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in first I used 
 $model->file = UploadedFile::getinstancebyname($model,'file');

but right is to use
 $model->file = UploadedFile::getinstance($model,'file');

Answer (score 2):

Illegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key.

You function is defined as getInstanceByName($name), but you are calling it using getinstancebyname($model,'file')

Something wrong there

Comment: where do you see it?

Comment: according to your code $name should be a key in your array right? Before the line 'return isset($files[$name]) ? new static($files[$name]) : null;' add a die('the key' . $name); Then you can see if you are actually using key which you think you are using.

Comment: $name is just function getInstanceByName($name) fome yii2